# Structure assignment in Linux fails in ARM but succeeds in x86

Tags: c, linux, arm, memory-alignment, sigbus

I've noticed something really strange.
say I've got the following structure defined

```
typedef struct
{
  uint32_t a;
  uint16_t b;
  uint32_t c;
} foo;
```

This structure is contained in a big buffer I receive from network.

The following code works in x86, but I receive `SIGBUS` on ARM.

```
extern void * buffer;
foo my_foo;
my_foo = (( foo * ) buffer)[0];
```

**replacing the pointer dereferencing with memcpy solved the issue.**

Searching about SIGBUS in ARM pointed me to the fact that this is related to memory alignment somwhow.

Can someone explain what's going on ?

Comment: Google: [structure serialization](https://www.google.ca/#q=structure+serialization) and see [Wikipedias serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).  *Alignment* and *endianess* being a constant theme.  Even if the **ARM** was to support this, it is going to break on a *big endian* CPU.  You need to annotate the `struct` as packed or the `memcpy()` may work (not `SIGBUS`), but it won't function properly.

Comment: [How to trap unaligned memory access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548059/how-to-trap-unaligned-memory-access) has some additional information on this issue with **ARM Linux**.  However, I think your underlying mechanism is flawed.  There are lots of serialization routines, protocols, and frameworks (`ntohl()`, `ntohs()`, [protobufs](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/), JSON, [XSD](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/), [XDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation), etc).

Comment: @artlessnoise thanks for the comments, but why the -1 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You said it yourself: there are memory alignment restrictions on your particular processor, and `buffer` is not aligned right to permit reading larger than a byte from it. The assignment is probably compiled into three moves of larger entities.

With `memcpy()`, there are no alignment restrictions, it *has to* be able to copy between any two addresses, so it does whatever is needed to implement that. Probably copying byte-by-byte until the addresses are aligned, that's a common pattern.

As an aside, I find it clearer to write your code without array indexing:

```
extern const void *buffer;
const foo my_foo = *(const foo *) buffer;
```

Answer (score 3):

C Standard [ISO/IEC 9899:2011] - 6.3.2.3, paragraph 7:

> > A pointer to an object or incomplete type may be converted to a pointer to a different object or incomplete type. **If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the pointed-to type, the behavior is undefined.**

[Source: CERT Secure Coding Standards](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/EXP36-C.+Do+not+convert+pointers+into+more+strictly+aligned+pointer+types)

Answer (score 1):

ARM-based systems expect structures to be aligned on a word boundary. If it is not the case you can have different behaviours (in the linux kernel for instance, these behaviours are described in `/proc/cpu/alignement` and one of them is to send a SIGBUS).

What you did with `memcpy()` is that you have forced the data structure alignment.

Answer (score 0):

i was developing some download application on freescale imx a while back....had a memory alignment problem there(requirement was that executable be in multiple of 512 bytes)...Fundamental difference between arm and x86...But the thing to remember with memcpy is that it does a byte by byte copy ...So, it might work but please be sure to check for run-time problems...Donot be fooled by memcpy...Always a good idea to have a memory aligned structure for your specific platform.