# Why movzbl is used in assembly when casting unsigned char to signed data types?

Tags: c, assembly, casting, mov, zero-extension

I'm learning data movement(`MOV`) in assembly.
I tried to compile some code to see the assembly in a x86_64 Ubuntu 18.04 machine:

```
typedef unsigned char src_t;
typedef xxx dst_t;

dst_t cast(src_t *sp, dst_t *dp) {
    *dp = (dst_t)*sp;
    return *dp;
}
```

where `src_t` is `unsigned char`. As for the `dst_t`, I tried `char`, `short`, `int` and `long`.
The result is shown below:

```
// typedef unsigned char src_t;
// typedef char dst_t;
//  movzbl  (%rdi), %eax
//  movb    %al, (%rsi)

// typedef unsigned char src_t;
// typedef short dst_t;
//  movzbl  (%rdi), %eax
//  movw    %ax, (%rsi)

// typedef unsigned char src_t;
// typedef int dst_t;
//  movzbl  (%rdi), %eax
//  movl    %eax, (%rsi)

// typedef unsigned char src_t;
// typedef long dst_t;
//  movzbl  (%rdi), %eax
//  movq    %rax, (%rsi)
```

I wonder why `movzbl` is used in every case? Shouldn't it correspond to `dst_t`?
Thanks!

Comment: *where `src_t` is `unsigned char`*  When you cast a `char` pointer to another type, if the source memory isn't actually of the type you cast to, you are violating [the strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule), and you may also be violating any alignment restrictions your system imposes - like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114491/structure-assignment-in-linux-fails-in-arm-but-succeeds-in-x86).

Comment: @AndrewHenle: the OP is casting the `*sp` *value* to `int`, not the *pointer* `sp` to `int *`.  Strict aliasing doesn't come into it.  From their 2nd code block, we see `typedef unsigned char src_t;`  I think just `unsigned` (int) in the first code block is a typo.  I fixed that mistake in how the question is presented.

Comment: @fuz: The return value really is just `al` when `dst_t` is `char`.  The x86-64 System V ABI specifies that high bits of return-value register can hold garbage.  (And even the unwritten convention that clang relies on of [extending narrow args to 32-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706721/is-a-sign-or-zero-extension-required-when-adding-a-32bit-offset-to-a-pointer-for/36760539#36760539) only applies to args, not return values.)  I posted an answer here that addresses this question from all the possible angles I could think of :P

Comment: @AndrewHenle:   (edit: you deleted your comment while I was typing this). Why are you assuming that the caller passed the address of something other than a `dst_t` object as the 2nd arg?  That's also clearly not what the OP is asking about; the generated asm makes sense for the no-UB case (as it must), and that's what's being asked about, not inlining into some unspecified caller.

Comment: @PeterCordes There's not context provided.  It's more of a "be careful" warning, hence it's just a comment.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Fair enough I guess, but would you really comment to "be careful" on every question involving a function that takes a pointer arg?  Anyway, the `movzbl` load would still be there (for the return value) even if we remove the `dp` output arg entirely.  Storing the result as well as returning does nicely expose the fact that the compiler is widening more (or apparently "less" for rax) than the width of `dst_t` which we can see from the reg in the store.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If you're wondering why not `movzbw (%rdi), %ax` for `short`**, that's because writing to 8-bit and 16-bit partial registers has to merge with the previous high bytes.

Writing a 32-bit register like EAX implicitly zero-extends into the full RAX, avoiding a false dependency on the old value of RAX or any ALU merging uop.  ([Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6))

**The "normal" way to load a byte on x86 is with `movzbl` or `movsbl`**, same as on a RISC machine like ARM `ldrb` or `ldrsb`, or MIPS `lbu` / `lb`.

The weird-CISC thing that GCC usually avoids is a merge with the old value that replaces only the low bits, like `movb (%rdi), %al`.  [Why doesn't GCC use partial registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers)  Clang is more reckless and will more often write partial regs, not just read them for stores.  You might well see clang load into just `%al` and store when `dst_t` is `signed char`.

---

**If you're wondering why not `movsbl (%rdi), %eax`** (sign-extension)

**The *source* value is unsigned, therefore zero-extension** (not sign-extension) is the correct way to widen it according to C semantics.  To get `movsbl`, you'd need `return (int)(signed char)c`.

In `*dp = (dst_t)*sp;` the cast to `dst_t` is already implicit from the assignment to `*dp`.

---

**The value-range for `unsigned char` is 0..255 (on x86 where CHAR_BIT = 8).**

Zero-extending this to `signed int` can produce a value range from `0..255`, i.e. preserving every value as signed non-negative integers.

Sign-extending this to `signed int` would produce a value range from `-128..+127`, changing the value of `unsigned char` values >= 128.  That conflicts with C semantics for widening conversions preserving values.

---

> Shouldn't it correspond to `dst_t`?

It has to widen *at least* as wide as `dst_t`.  It turns out that widening to 64-bit by using `movzbl` (with the top 32 bits handled by implicit zero-extension writing a 32-bit reg) is the most efficient way to widen at all.

Storing to `*dp` is a nice demo that the asm is for a `dst_t` with a width other than 32-bit.

Anyway, note that there's only one conversion happening.  Your `src_t` gets converted to `dst_t` in al/ax/eax/rax with a load instruction, and stored to dst_t of whatever width.  And also left there as the return value.

A zero-extending load is normal even if you're just going to read the low byte of that result.

Comment: Often a Peter Cordes answer is recognizable just from the first few lines that get right to the heart of a technical issue.