# C --- Problems with declaration (redefinition) of global variables

Tags: c, char, global-variables, redefinition

so I'm trying to write my own 'malloc' library and I am having problems with my global variables.

In the code below you can see, that I'm creating an int pointer to write an integer into the char-array, and that int pointer points to the first byte of my char-array, thinking it's memory for an integer.

```
char myMemory[1048576];

int* pMem = (int*)(&myMemory[0]);
*pMem = (1048576-5);
myMemory[4] = 'f';

//... and so forth
```

For the last line I get the following error message:

```
redefinition of 'myMemory' with a different type 'int [4]' vs 'char [1048576]'
```

For 
    *pMem = (...);
I get the following

```
invalid operands to binary expression 'int*' and 'int*'
```

maybe I'm not allowed to change global variables globally, when I did the same stuff in a testing function everything worked.

It's been impossible for me to find that out on the internet, because everybody is asking how to change global variables in functions which is..

I hope someone can help me with this, because I think otherwise I will soon burn my house. Thank you in advance.

Tim

Comment: Show a minimal complete program that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Are these lines outside of a function?

Comment: @Eugene Sh. yes they are

Comment: Well, you can't put statements outside of a function. I think you might want to start with a project a bit simpler than `malloc` because looks like your general C knowledge needs to be ramped up a bit.

Comment: @EugeneSh. well that doesn't help very much. is there a way to define these variables without an init-function, because i don't want one?

Comment: There are three basic things you can do with variables: *define*, *initialize* and *assign*. First two can be done outside of a function. Third one cannot. But if you even find a way to initialize your  `myMemory`, it will move it from `.bss` section to `.data` effectively increasing the size of your executable by the size of this array (+1MB).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quick Summary:**

That error really doesn't apply to what you're trying to do - implement `malloc()`.

**Fix**

Use a compiler or compiler argument that doesn't give you the `redefinition of 'myMemory' with a different type 'int [4]' vs 'char [1048576]'` error.

**Full Answer**

Strictly speaking, this code

```
int* pMem = (int*)(&myMemory[0]);
```

is a [strict aliasing violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) and potentially violates [**6.3.2.3 Pointers**, p7](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7) of the C standard:

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.

Your error

```
redefinition of 'myMemory' with a different type 'int [4]' vs 'char [1048576]'
```

is because you violated the strict aliasing rule.

In general, in C you can not take memory that didn't start as having a specific type and treat it as having another type - with the exception that you can always treat any memory as `char` type.  You can't take a `char` array and treat it as an `int` array, for example.

That's the strict aliasing rule.

But you can take an `int` array and treat is as a `char` array - or `signed char` or `unsigned char` array.

And even if the memory did somehow start as an `int` but all you have is a `char` pointer (or `void` pointer) to it, when you cast it back and access it as an `int`, the memory has to be properly aligned for the platform you're on.

Your code may or may not do that - you won't know for sure until you actually run it.  If it doesn't meed alignment requirements, you might get a `SIGBUS` or some other failure - [like this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114491/structure-assignment-in-linux-fails-in-arm-but-succeeds-in-x86)

Breaking any of those rules results in undefined behavior.

**BUT**

In this case you're "trying to write [your] own 'malloc' library", and `malloc()` is provided by the implementation, **so those rules don't really apply** as you're providing a part of the **C implementation itself**.

Why?  Why don't those rules apply to the implementation of the C environment itself?

They can't, because of [**7.22.3 Memory management functions**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3):

> The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement and then used to access such an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated

You simply can not do that in strictly-conforming C code.

Memory managed by `malloc()` (and `calloc()` and ...) starts as "untyped", but you can't have such "untyped" memory in conformant C code.  What about using `void *` to reference the memory?  You can't do pointer arithmetic on `void *` pointers in conformant C code.  And you're going to have to do pointer arithmetic to manage the memory.  So you pretty much have to use pointers to *some type* to manage the memory.

And you can't use arrays to avoid such pointer arithmetic, because those arrays also have to have a concrete type.

So you have to "type" the memory you manage in your `malloc()` implementation, yet when that memory gets passed to a caller as the result of a `malloc()` call, the strict aliasing rule gets violated.

If you manage your memory right, your `malloc()` implemenation won't violate the alignment restrictions of **6.3.2.3 Pointers**, p7.

**Why does so much code break these rules?**

Because the x86 platform most people writing code use is **EXTREMELY FORGIVING** on misaligned accesses.

Comment: Thank you, that was very interesting!