Intentionally Disregarding Excess Elements in Initializer Warning Under GCC
I am attempting to abuse static initialization to build a menu tree without any runtime initialization:
typedef struct {
    menu_entry_t entry;
    uint16_t can_loop:1;
    uint16_t sz:15;
    uint32_t entries[0];
} __attribute__((packed)) menu_data_t;

static menu_data_t menu_list[] = {
    {
        .entry = MENU_COIL_POWER,
        .can_loop = 0,
        .sz = 5,
        .entries = {
            RGB(0x0F, 0x0A, 0x00),
            RGB(0x1F, 0x15, 0x00),
            RGB(0x3F, 0x29, 0x00),
            RGB(0x7F, 0x53, 0x00),
            RGB(0xFF, 0xA5, 0x00),
        }
    },
    {
        .entry = MENU_LED_MODE,
        .can_loop = 0,
        .sz = 3,
        .entries = {
            RGB(63, 63, 0),
            RGB(127, 127, 0),
            RGB(255, 255, 0),
        }
    },
    // ...
};

This builds but GCC, predictably complains about the initialization of the entries sub-array:
warning: excess elements in array initializer

How can I silence this specific warning?  I am fully aware that it is generated because I have declared uint32_t entries[0] with an array size of zero.  This is a paradigm I have exploited dynamically in the past via malloc(sizeof(menu_data_t) + num_entries * sizeof(uint32_t)); I am simply attempting to do this statically now.
So, in short, How can I disable GCC's excess elements in initializer warning (preferably something that can be fed into #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "...")?  Searching GCC's documentation doesn't seem to have an explicit -W flag for it (or, at least, it is called something unexpected)?
Some related research:

How can I ignore the warning "excess elements in struct initializer" - I am not overwriting an initialized field.  Also, -Wno-override-init didn't work anyway.
GCC force warning to be an error: excess elements in array initializer - I don't want an error, I want this to compile quietly.


@MysteryMoose This declaration uint32_t entries[0]; is not a valid C declaration.

Zero length arrays are a nonstandard GNU C extension, and can't be initialized statically (even if you suppress the warning, the initializer will just be ignored). C90 instead provides flexible array members, declared like entries[] instead of entries[0], and GCC does let you initialize them, according to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html

Oh, but you definitely can't have an array of such structs. It's fundamental in C that all elements of an array have the same size, so that indexing can be done with simple pointer arithmetic. I or someone else can write an answer later explaining exactly why this can't work, but you might as well start rewriting now.

Your code (and your question) is fundamentally broken because filling the entries member, if that could be done, with arrays of different sizes would mean each menu_data_t instance is a difference size, and then addressing the menu_list array of those structures would be broken. You could choose between making each menu_data_t structure have an entries array that is the same size, large enough to hold your largest case, or making entries be a pointer instead of an array, and putting the arrays elsewhere. (That is easily done with compound literals.)

@NateEldredge: Flexible array members started with C 1999, not 1990.

Downvote but not comment why?
And, indeed, this is not standard by any means.  I know standard dereferencing via [] will not work but manually calculated pointers will.  The deeper problem that I didn't catch immediately which Nate pointed out is that GCC isn't actually including the array data.

The key point here was trying to elide storage for the pointer.  I am shoehorning this into a way too tiny MCU and am counting bytes at this point.

too tiny MCU and am counting bytes at this point What MCU is it? It's 2024 now and you can buy stm32 BluePill with 20KB of memory for a dollar on aliexpress, stuff is cheap, and the save on pointers is most probably like negligible 8 bytes. You might consider investing like two dollars just for a bigger MCU.

@KamilCuk: If one is making 10,000 of something, adding an extra $2 to the cost of each would represent $20,000 of extra cost.

@KamilCuk: Additionally, often the choice of MCU is limited by required electrical ratings, peripherals, available area and other non-software considerations.  I would love to cram a large processor in everything but, ultimately, resource-constrained environments still exist and, due to the nature of supply and demand, always will.

Don't hardcode the menu structure! Write the menu in your favorite hierarchial text format (JSON, XML, etc.), and then use your favorite scripting language (Python, etc.) to convert the text file into C source. This way you more easily change the memory structure when necessary, and you can precalculate a lot of things. It is a lot easier and more efficient. It also opens a door for other things, like generating menu documentation automatically. Trust me, I have gone the same path as you have before.

Unrelated to the question, why are you allocating this in RAM and not flash?

@KamilCuk Professional MCU applications don't use some eval board and certainly not one from Aliexpress with extra fake parts. No matter how much memory you got, it's always gonna be best practices to not consume more than necessary. Within reason that is - I'm not sure why the OP decided to pack this struct. That's probably going to be a pain to work with.

it's always gonna be best practices For me, best practice is shortest time to market. Spending days optimizing for 8 bytes by researching, writing a stackoverflow question and then managing code with undefined behavior from the answer and then dealing with the unreadable mess that the code becomes is, in my experience, not worth the time and money in the long run. It results in buggy devices and unhappy clients.

@KamilCuk I would think that BoM cost is what most engineers are dealing with, more so than time to market. The kind of products I design go for at most 1000 PCBA per year but it's still a whole lot of money if you specify a MCU for $10 when you could have gotten one for $5.

@KamilCuk Though most often these problems arise from picking the wrong MCU to begin with, in the requirements phase of the project. Far too many would-be engineers pick the MCU first, then go look at the project requirements after. It is convenient to re-use a MCU you are already familiar with for sure, but MCUs go obsolete in no time these days, so that's dangerous thinking.

Anyway, the normal way to build up menu systems and the like in embedded firmware is to use pointers and linked lists, that end with a NULL pointer sentinel. They do consume an itty bit of extra flash since you need to store the address to the next item, but they are very flexible, maintainable and can be written in standard C. Relying on gcc extensions is a stupid idea in general, but particularly so in an embedded systems, where the more recent versions of gcc can't even be used because of all the compiler bugs.

@everybody: To be blunt, my choice of MCU has NOTHING to do with the question at hand and "change your MCU" isn't helpful.  The argument of MCU size for a particular effort will never be solved in some random comments forum as it is specific to my product, design choices, expected time to market, USD exchange rate, current zodiac sign, phase of the moon and number of millifotnights since the last Vernal Equinox.  Can we please stick to the focus of the question: statically initializing a data structure?

@lundin: Your point about compilers is well and standard C is well made.  I have implemented KamilCuk's solution below which allows me to drop the GCC extension, so at least that is now standard (modulo the discussion about UB on strict aliasing).

@MysteryMoose Alternatively, those who suggest that you run an external script to generate the C code aren't wrong, that's an easy way to create flexible programs at compile-time without abandoning standard C. Yet another alternative would be to cook up something with X-macros which would work too but not as readable.

Looking at GCC force warning to be an error: excess elements in array initializer and gcc source code, there is no option to silence the warning.
Notes: This is an XY question. It's asking about silencing a compiler warning. Instead consider researching how to properly initailize an array of structures with flexible array length.
The question additionally contains a false premise. All the "excess" data are ignored, they are not stored anywhere and can just be removed from the source code.
The array of lenght zero is a gcc extensions. As gcc documentation notes https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html prefer the C99 syntax.
Bottom line, ignoring your question, I do not think there exists way to statically initialize an array of structures with flexible array memebrs. I would do just pointers and forget about it. Note: the pointers themselves are const and can be stored in ROM.
#include <stdint.h>
typedef enum { MENU_COIL_POWER, MENU_LED_MODE } menu_entry_t;
#define RGB(a,b,c) a
typedef struct {
    menu_entry_t entry;
    uint16_t can_loop:1;
    uint16_t sz:15;
    uint32_t entries[];
} menu_data_t;
static menu_data_t a = {
    .entry = MENU_COIL_POWER,
    .can_loop = 0,
    .sz = 5,
    .entries = {
        RGB(0x0F, 0x0A, 0x00),
        RGB(0x1F, 0x15, 0x00),
        RGB(0x3F, 0x29, 0x00),
        RGB(0x7F, 0x53, 0x00),
        RGB(0xFF, 0xA5, 0x00),
    }
};
static menu_data_t b = {
    .entry = MENU_LED_MODE,
    .can_loop = 0,
    .sz = 3,
    .entries = {
        RGB(63, 63, 0),
        RGB(127, 127, 0),
        RGB(255, 255, 0),
    }
};
static menu_data_t *const menu_list[] = {&a, &b};

If this is not enough for you and you really do care about it, you would write a program to generate the bytes that compose of the array or manage the bytes that compose of the array yourself, and use deserialization or abstractions to get the data from the bytes into C programming language. For example on X86 machine the following code outputs 3 7f7f:
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
enum { MENU_COIL_POWER, MENU_LED_MODE };
typedef uint16_t menu_entry_t;
#define RGB(a,b,c)  /*little endian*/ a,b,c,0
typedef struct {
    menu_entry_t entry;
    uint16_t can_loop:1;
    uint16_t sz:15;
    uint32_t entries[];
} __attribute__((packed)) menu_data_t;
#define MAKE_MENU_DATA(entry, can_loop, sz)   \
    /* assuming some bit order and endianess of target platform */ \
    entry, entry >> 8, sz << 1 | can_loop, sz >> 7
static _Alignas(menu_data_t) unsigned char menu_data[] = {
    MAKE_MENU_DATA(MENU_COIL_POWER, 0, 5),
    RGB(0x0F, 0x0A, 0x00),
    RGB(0x1F, 0x15, 0x00),
    RGB(0x3F, 0x29, 0x00),
    RGB(0x7F, 0x53, 0x00),
    RGB(0xFF, 0xA5, 0x00),
    MAKE_MENU_DATA(MENU_LED_MODE, 0, 3),
    RGB(63, 63, 0),
    RGB(127, 127, 0),
    RGB(255, 255, 0),
};
menu_data_t *get_menu_data(unsigned i) { 
    char *pnt = menu_data;
    while (1) {
        menu_data_t *tmp = (void*)pnt;
        if (!i--) return tmp;
        pnt += sizeof(menu_data_t) + sizeof(uint32_t) * tmp->sz;
    }
}
int main() {
    printf("%d %x\n", get_menu_data(1)->sz, get_menu_data(1)->entries[1]);
}

Note: that code above has undefined behavior - the char array is cast to menu_data_t. It might be preferable to write good unit tests to test what compiler code generates, and put the "getter" into a separate translation unit and not optimize it.

Appreciate the change in frame of question.  _Alignas with a macro to directly lay out the bytes is exactly the answer I was looking for.  Then I can just plop a pointer to my type right on top of it.

@MysteryMoose: Can you, though? There's the strict aliasing rule to contend with.

How so, the underlying type is unsigned char?  It has been a while since I did a deep dive into aliasing rules but, AFAICR, the issues with aliasing are more related to alignment / typing than anything else (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule#99010).  According to that article, there is a carve-out for unsigned char and, by extension, uint8_t.

The carveout in 6.5.1p7 allows you to access an object of any effective type through an lvalue of character type (which, if we're being technical, is not guaranteed to include uint8_t).  But not vice versa.  If you have an array whose objects are of effective type unsigned char, 6.5.1p7 does not give you permission to access it through an lvalue of type menu_data_t.  So on that basis, I think the code in this answer is actually UB.

@MysteryMoose: The linked article actually says this as well.  "It's always assumed that char* aliases other types. However this won't work the other way: there's no assumption that your struct aliases a buffer of chars."

@MysteryMoose: What you can do is memcpy the unsigned char buffer into an object of type menu_data_t, and hope that the compiler optimizes out the copy.

@NateEldredge: I see your point.  Though, doesn't the cast through void * allow us to freely convert the pointer to whatever we want?  Per Lundin's answer here, I am changing the type of the pointer (which is legal) and it is my responsibility to ensure the bytes are in the correct order to be accessed through the new pointer.  AFAICT, the only thing that should change in the emitted bytecode are the struct offsets in the load instructions.

@MysteryMoose: This is turning into its own question, but: Yes, you can convert the pointer to whatever you want; that's fine.  But that doesn't really have anything to do with the strict aliasing rule.  It took me a long time to realize this.  It's about what type of pointers you can use to access a given chunk of memory.  It doesn't matter how you arranged for the pointer to point there, via whatever chain of conversions or some other form of magic.  None of those pointer conversions change the effective type of the actual memory.

@MysteryMoose: At the end of the day, your block of memory still has effective type unsigned char, and you're attempting to access it by dereferencing a pointer of type menu_data_t *, producing an lvalue expression of type menu_data_t, and that's not compatible with unsigned char under the rule, and that's undefined behavior.

@NateEldredge: if you want, I can ask this as a formal question as this is really useful information.  That said, I get you: pointer conversion = defined, accessing data THROUGH that pointer = undefined.

It has been asked many times. Research [c] tag with strict aloas violation on this forum, you'll find many results. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+casting+char+strict+alias+violation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165134/correct-portable-way-to-interpret-buffer-as-a-struct

@MysteryMoose Nate is correct that placing some other type on top of a character array would be a strict aliasing violation, which is a separate issue than alignment. To dodge strict aliasing you would have to place the character array in a union with the custom type, then it is ok.

@MysteryMoose To offer some insight how this is usually done in low-level MCU applications however, you often implement static memory pools as a replacement for dynamic allocation. And then you run into strict aliasing. This is solved by avoiding "PC compilers" like gcc/clang if possible, or if not possible then always compile with -fno-strict-aliasing (the Linux kernal does the same afaik since it is stuck with gcc).

@MysteryMoose Example of how this is done here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667901/584518. But that post neither addresses strict aliasing nor alignment, which need to be considered.
